# Foreign Key constraint when inserting rows in table

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an error while trying to insert some rows in a table. It's an association problem between my entities but I don't know how to solve it.

banque_statistiquecolle table is empty and I can't insert any row, banque_colle contains some rows. Rows I'm trying to insert are linked to these banque_colle rows.

Query :

```
INSERT INTO banque_statistiquecolle (id, colle_id, effectif, moyenne, mediane, note100, major, minor)
SELECT sc.id, sc.colle_id, sc.effectif, sc.moyenne, sc.mediane, sc.note100, sc.major, sc.minor
FROM statistiquecolle_groupe scg 
LEFT JOIN  statistiquecolle sc ON sc.id = scg.statistiquecolle_id
WHERE scg.groupe_id = 1 
AND sc.id NOT IN (SELECT sc1.id
                  FROM statistiquecolle_groupe scg1 
                  LEFT JOIN  statistiquecolle sc1 ON sc1.id = scg1.statistiquecolle_id
                  WHERE scg1.groupe_id != 1)
```

The error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails ('tutotour_tharmo18052017test'.'banque_statistiquecolle', 
CONSTRAINT 'FK_5C1250C5F0B40A43' FOREIGN KEY ('colle_id') REFERENCES 'banque_colle' ('id'))
```

BanqueStatistiqueColle Entity :

```
/**
* BanqueStatistiqueColle
*
* @ORM\Table(name="banque_statistiquecolle")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class BanqueStatistiqueColle
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\PACES\BanqueBundle\Entity\BanqueColle")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="colle_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $colle;

{Other properties}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\PACES\BanqueBundle\Entity\BanqueRepartitionColle", mappedBy="idStatColle",
 * cascade={"all"})
 */
private $repartitionsColle;
```

BanqueColle Entity :

```
/**
 * Colle
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="banque_colle")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"colle"="BanqueColle", "colleQC"="BanqueColleQC"})
 */
class BanqueColle
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

{Other properties}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PACES\BanqueBundle\Entity\BanqueStatistiqueColle", mappedBy="colle", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $statsColle;
```

Comment: You could start by matching all sc.colle_id to banque_colle_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails

When two table are binded with foreign key relationship, in that case you can only insert those values in child table which are already present in parent table.

Your foreign key relation is:

```
FOREIGN KEY ('colle_id') REFERENCES 'banque_colle' ('id'))
```

so you can insert only those value in `colle_id` which are already their in `'banque_colle' ('id'))` column.

Comment: Thank you, I just forgot I deleted banque_colle content so it wouldn't work.